# Trying to open a py file inside Pycharm but it opens outside of Pycharm for some reason

Tags: python, pycharm, artificial-intelligence, vosk

```
    elif "go online" in result["text"]:
        os.system("clear")
        stream.stop_stream()
        print("Sir: " + result["text"])
        speak("Switching to online mode")
        os.system("open /Users/************/PycharmProjects/K.I.T.T/K"
                  ".I.T.T._online.py")
        quit
```

Instead of opening a new tab inside Pycharm it just opens 3 windows outside with a different ide? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: it uses the default executable to open `.py` files, the easiest to change  that would be to go to a python file, left click it, choose open with, tick that box, select PyCharm (if you're on windows), regardless of all that, what are you really even trying to do?

Comment: Thanks! With opening that second python file im switching to my online assistant or atleast thats the plan

Answer (score 1):

The `.py` being inside a PycharmProjects folder doesn't mean that it will open in PyCharm. You can either go into your default program settings and set `.py` files to always open in PyCharm, or you could [open the file from terminal](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/opening-files-from-command-line.html) by setting the location of PyCharm as a path variable and calling:

```
pycharm.sh ~/MyProject
```